# Automatically update attributes of instance based on other class instances

Tags: python, class, attributes

Let's suppose I have a class named `Rectangle` and another named `Force`:

```
class Rectangle(object):
    def __init__(self, l, h, x0, y0):
        self.l = l
        self.h = h
        self.x0 = x0
        self.y0 = y0

    @property
    def vertices(self):
        return [(self.x0, self.y0), (self.x0, self.y0+self.h),
                (self.x0+self.l, self.y0+self.h), (self.x0+self.l, self.y0)]


class Force(object):
    def __init__(self, val, pt):
        self.value = val
        self.point = pt
```

Let's say I initialize

```
>>> r = Rectangle(10,6,0,0)
>>> f = Force(10,r.vertices[2])
```

And I therefore get

```
>>> r.vertices
 [(0, 0), (0, 6), (10, 6), (10, 0)]
>>> f.point
 (10, 6)
```

Now, I change the height of the rectangle to `h=5`

```
>>> r.h=5
>>> r.vertices
 [(0, 0), (0, 5), (10, 5), (10, 0)]
```

Can I somehow automatically update `f.point`? Like passing by reference (which however does not exist in python).

Comment: Maybe it's an overkill but you can try the Observer pattern http://www.giantflyingsaucer.com/blog/?p=5117.  The observer patter is something like: `A software design pattern in which an object, called the subject, maintains a list of its dependents, called observers, and notifies them automatically of any state changes`

Comment: @Roomm Looks indeed pretty like an overkill, but also very interesting! I will have a better look this evening